# git pull form bash returns fatal : Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)

Tags: git, bash

In bash, how can I say, `clone` the repository if directory doesn't exist and `git pull` if repository exist?

I have this , but it gives me `fatal : Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=~/test/repo1
if [ -d $DIR]; then
    git pull
else
    cd ~/test
    git clone git@github.com/repo
fi
```

Comment: remove **all** the backticks. What do you think they are doing?

Comment: You will need a space between `$DIR` and `]` -- the `[` *command* demands that `]` is it's last argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it exists (i.e. -d $DIR]; is true) you have to perform a changedir before you pull like so: cd $DIR. 
I don't really get the git clone, shouldn't it be something with repo1 in it?

Comment: Presumably the `...` elides the `repo1` bit of that url to make this make sense.

Comment: ok. that makes perfectly sense. although i'd rather put the complete url in the question (may it be just an example or not), the dots ain't that much of a timesafer but introduce a lot of ambiguity.

Comment: I agree that at very least the `repo1.git` bit should have been left in the URL.